# Scraping HTML with PHP and encoding problems

Tags: php, encoding, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the following url with PHP:
http://www.clubedoricardo.com.br/Produto/Smartphone-Samsung-Galaxy-Win-2-Duos-G360-Cinza-Dual-Chip-4G-Tela-45-Camera-5MP-Frontal-2MP-Quad-Core-12Ghz-8GB/44-491-496-568187

```
$url="http://www.clubedoricardo.com.br/Produto/Smartphone-Samsung-Galaxy-Win-2-Duos-G360-Cinza-Dual-Chip-4G-Tela-45-Camera-5MP-Frontal-2MP-Quad-Core-12Ghz-8GB/44-491-496-568187";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$page_content = $dom->saveHTML();
echo($page_content);
```

But the text comes with weird characters. I tried encoding with UTF-8 and ISO-8859, but nothing changes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When i follow the link You provided, a blank website appears.
Try:

```
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($url, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the URL now. Should I try "loadHTML" or "loadHTMLFile" ?